# Gnuplot: data normalization of multiple dataset in one file

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Image one file with 250 datasets with varying length (2000 +-500) lines and 11 columns. Here a comprehensive small example:

**file.sum:**

```
0.00000e+00      9.51287e-09
1.15418e-04      8.51287e-09
4.16445e-04      7.51287e-09
8.53721e-04      6.51287e-09
1.42697e-03      5.51287e-09
1.70302e-03      4.51287e-09
2.27189e-03      3.51287e-09
2.54732e-03      1.51287e-09
3.11304e-03      0.51287e-09


0.00000e+00      13.28378e-09 
1.15418e-04      12.28378e-09 
3.19663e-04      11.28378e-09 
5.78178e-04      10.28378e-09 
8.67479e-04      09.28378e-09 
1.20883e-03      08.28378e-09 
1.58817e-03      07.28378e-09 
1.75840e-03      06.28378e-09 
2.21069e-03      05.28378e-09
```

I wanted to display every 10 datasets and normalize it to the first element. The first value to normalize is 9.51287e-09 and the second would be 13.28378e-09. Of course with this massive dataset, I can not do it manually or even split the file.

So far I got every ten'th dataset but with the normalization, I do have my problems.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset

set xrange [0:0.1]

plot for [val=1:250:10] 'file.sum' i val u 1:11 w l
```

Working of this example:

**plot.gp:**

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset

set xrange [0:0.01]

plot for [val=1:2:1] 'file.sum' i val u 1:2 w l
```

Some hints I found in:

- [Gnuplot: data normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669052/gnuplot-data-normalization)

I guess you can write a awk script to handle this, but there may be a more gnuplot friendlier way. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one file with data sections each separated by two or more empty lines you can use the script below.

In gnuplot console check `help pseudocolumns`. `column(-2)` tells you in which block you are and `column(0)` tells you wich line of this block you are (counting starts from 0).
Define a function `Normalized(n)` which does the following: if you are in the first line of a subblock put the value of `column(n)` into the variable `y0`. All values of this block will now be divided by `y0`. Also check `help ternary`.

In case you want a legend for the blocks you can plot a dummy plot, actually plotting `NaN` (i.e. nothing) but place an entry for the key.

**Code:**

```
### normalize each block by its first value
reset session
set colorsequence classic

$Data <<EOD
0.00000e+00      9.51287e-09
1.15418e-04      8.51287e-09
4.16445e-04      7.51287e-09
8.53721e-04      6.51287e-09
1.42697e-03      5.51287e-09
1.70302e-03      4.51287e-09
2.27189e-03      3.51287e-09
2.54732e-03      1.51287e-09
3.11304e-03      0.51287e-09


0.00000e+00      13.28378e-09 
1.15418e-04      12.28378e-09 
3.19663e-04      11.28378e-09 
5.78178e-04      10.28378e-09 
8.67479e-04      09.28378e-09 
1.20883e-03      08.28378e-09 
1.58817e-03      07.28378e-09 
1.75840e-03      06.28378e-09 
2.21069e-03      05.28378e-09 
EOD

Normalized(n) = column(n)/(column(0)==0 ? y0=column(n) : y0)

plot $Data u 1:(Normalized(2)):(myBlocks=column(-2)+1) w lp pt 7 lc var notitle, \
     for [i=0:myBlocks-1] '' u 1:(NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i+1 ti sprintf("Block %d",i)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]